# Junit and testing a method

Tags: java, junit

Consider the following code:

```
public void methodA(String arg1, String arg2) {
  String resultDB;
  ....process something

  /**do a db call using arg1 - currently the table is not yet
     defined in the db **/
  //String resultDB = result value from db call;
  if (resultDB equals VALUEA)
     do some processing
  }

..further processing using arg1 and arg2
}
```

Currently the db table is not available but rest of the logic can be executed.

How can I test this method for various paths. The resultDB may equal/or not equal "VALUEA". Is there anyway in Junit to test the paths bearing the fact that resultDB is not a argument to the method but local variable.

Answer (score 2):

The question is: how is resultDB getting its value from?! Most likely, you are calling a method of another object. In that case, that other object might need to be a *mock*; and then you are able to specify the behavior of that mock within your test.

In other words: you gain control over the value that resultDB will have; and then you can use *asserts* to check that your method does what you expect to happen for the various options.

And it might be worth looking into "clean code" principles; I think that your code is doing way too many things in one method; and that your code depends on too many parameters that drive the paths within the method. Basically, you should simplify the whole thing; best: one method per case; which can then be tested easily.